# C++ Overloading different with signed and unsigned int

Tags: c++

When compiling C++ with overloaded function definitions why is the promotion behaviour different between signed and unsigned integer types?  Is this expected behaviour?

In the example below, the call to "fail" in main is ambiguous but the call to "pass" is not.

```
unsigned int fail(unsigned int a) {
  return a;
}

unsigned int fail(unsigned short a) {
  return a;
}

int pass(int a) {
  return a;
}

int pass(short a) {
  return a;
}


int main(){

  unsigned char a;
  char b;
  fail(a);
  pass(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output (from clang, VS compiler gives something similar):

```
fail.cpp:22:3: error: call to 'fail' is ambiguous
  fail(a);
  ^~~~
fail.cpp:1:14: note: candidate function
unsigned int fail(unsigned int a) {
             ^
fail.cpp:5:14: note: candidate function
unsigned int fail(unsigned short a) {
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: note that `char` is its own type that can be either `signed` or `unsigned`

Comment: It might be because the compiler hit `fail()` first, although to be honest I'm not the most familiar with C++ compilers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are the results of integer promotion different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711124/why-are-the-results-of-integer-promotion-different)

Answer (score 5):

According to [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) (emphasis mine):

> The following implicit conversions are classified as integral promotions:
>
> - `signed char` [...] can be converted to `int`;
> - `unsigned char` [...] can be converted to `int` if it can hold its entire value range, and `unsigned int` otherwise;
> - `char` can be converted to `int` or `unsigned int` depending on the underlying type: `signed char` or `unsigned char` (see above);
>
> **Note that all other conversions are not promotions; for example, overload resolution chooses `char` -> `int` (promotion) over `char` -> `short` (conversion).**

In your case, given that `int` is able to hold the entire value range of both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, only `int pass(int a)` is a promotion which is more preferable than the remaining three which are conversions, and there is no preference among the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Those `implicit conversions` indeed follow different rules.

- `char` -> `int`   is a promotion
- `char` -> `short` is a conversion

and promotion is chosen over conversion because it forbids any precision loss. That's why `pass` passes.

Whereas

- `unsigned char` -> `unsigned int` is a promotion only if `int` can't represent the full range of values `unsigned char`s can; if not, the promotion is `unsigned char` -> `int`.

I suspect that, in your case, `int` can indeed represent all values in the range of `unsigned char`. This means that `fail` has a choice between two two-steps conversion paths: `unsigned char` -> `int` -> `unsigned int` and `unsigned char` -> `int` -> `unsigned short` and can't decide between them.

source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion